# Taking data from an XML document and writing it to another XML document with python

Tags: python, xml

I've been trying for a while now to do this.

Basically, i have an XML document in the following format(which contains the information i need - the ID and coordinates of some points):

```
<root>
    <!-- Title element missing here -->
    <Table>
        <Point>
            <ID>Point1</ID>
            <latitude>numbers</latitude>
            <longitude>numbers</longitude>
        </Point>
    </Table>            <!-- This line should be eliminated -->
    <Table>             <!-- This line should be eliminated -->
        <Point>
            <ID>Point2</ID>
            <latitude>numbers</latitude>
            <longitude>numbers</longitude>
        </Point>
    </Table>
</root>
```

What i need to do is to take this document and output it in a different format (like i displayed above, in the original XML file), without changing the original XML file.

I wrote the following code for the above task, but i hit a brick wall, so to speak. I am also rather new to python as well.

```
from lxml import etree
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
doc=etree.parse('test2.xml')
root=doc.getroot()
elements=root.findall(".//Point")

root=ET.Element('root')
title=ET.SubElement(root,'Title')
title.text="Title"
table=ET.SubElement(root,'Table')
for element in elements:
    point=ET.SubElement(table,'Point')
    elem=ET.SubElement(point,'ID')
    elem.text="Name"
    elem2=ET.SubElement(point,'latitude')
    elem2.text="coords"
    elem3=ET.SubElement(point,'longitude')
    elem3.text="coords"
ET.dump(root)  # using ET.dump just to display the output in the python SHELL
```

The code above gives me the following output in SHELL, which is what i need.

```
<root>
    <Title>Title</Title>
    <Table>
        <Point>
            <ID>Name</ID>
            <latitude>coords</latitude>
            <longitude>coords</longitude>
        </Point>
        <Point>
            <ID>Name</ID>
            <latitude>coords</latitude>
            <longitude>coords</longitude>
        </Point>
    </Table>
</root>
```

My problem comes when i have to take the values of `ID`,`latitude` and `longitude` from the original XML file and writing the whole new document in a new XML file, with `pretty_print` as well, for easier reading. I simply can't fingure it out. Some tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to copy the Point element from the original XML, you can just do:

```
from copy import deepcopy
for element in elements:
    table.append(deepcopy(element))
```

If you want to manipulate the values in some way, you can iterate over the element:

```
point=ET.SubElement(table,'Point')
for subelement in element:
    elem = ET.SubElement(point, subelement.tag)
    if elem.tag == 'ID':
        elem.text = dowhatyouwantwith(subelement.text)
    elif ....
```

Also, do you really need to use both `lxml.etree` and `xml.etree` at the same time? Why don't you just pick one of them and stick to it?

Comment: Implemented the `copy` part, as i wasn't required to do any further processing on the data. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ET.write()` and `xml.dom.minidom` to achieve what you want. 
(Considering we do not use `lxml` and use only standard Python's ElementTree)

Just extending your code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import xml.dom.minidom
doc=ET.parse('test2.xml')
root=doc.getroot()
elements=root.findall(".//Point")

root=ET.Element('root')
title=ET.SubElement(root,'Title')
title.text="Title"
table=ET.SubElement(root,'Table')
for element in elements:
    point=ET.SubElement(table,'Point')
    elem=ET.SubElement(point,'ID')
    elem.text="Name"
    elem2=ET.SubElement(point,'latitude')
    elem2.text="coords"
    elem3=ET.SubElement(point,'longitude')
    elem3.text="coords"
ET.dump(root)  # using ET.dump just to display the output in the python SHELL

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write('test3.xml') # This is enough but not yet pretty-print

# Using xml.dom.minidom to parse the non-pretty file to make it pretty
a = xml.dom.minidom.parse('test3.xml')
pretty_xml_as_string = a.toprettyxml()
with open('test3.xml', 'w') as f:
    f.write(pretty_xml_as_string) # Write again in pretty-print format
```

Comment: Thank you for the `pretty_print` suggestion. Helped me a lot.

Comment: Hi @Alex-C if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this !!